# How would i split a string once every n characters

Tags: lua

Let's say i have a string:

```
local n = 2
local Name = "JohnIsNice"
```

How would i split it every n characters so the string will become
{"Jo", "hn", "Is", "Ni", "Ce"}

I don't really know how to do it so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for m in Name:gmatch(('.'):rep(n)) do
  print(m)
end
```

`('.'):rep(n)` will generate a string with n dots which represents a pattern matches n characters.

`Name:gmatch()` returns all the matches.

Comment: Note that a remaining less than n characters will be silently ignored. Could be fixed by using a numeric for loop or `.?` instead.